# Laravel data not sending to db

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm not really sure how to best explain it in the title, I have data parsing as suggestions for an RCS project, when I click send the DB changes the values but they are left empty.

My Create blade:

```
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
          <form action='/' method="post">

              @csrf
              <input type="hidden" name="type" value="file">
              <div class='form-group col-3'>
                  <label for='msisdn'>MSISDN</label>
                  <input type='text' id='msisdn' name='msisdn' class='form-control'>
              </div>

              <div class='form-group col'>
                  <label for='url'>File URL</label>
                  <input type='text' id='url' name='url' class='form-control'>
              </div>

              <div>
                  <h4>Suggestions</h4>

                  <div class="form-inline form-group">
                      <div class='form-group'>
                          <div class="col">
                              <label for='suggestion_type'>Type</label>
                              <select class="form-control suggestion" id="suggestion_type" name="suggestion_type" onchange="if ($('#suggestion_type').val() == 'text') { $('#suggestion_data_x').hide() } else { $('#suggestion_data_x').show() }">
                                  <option value="text">Text</option>
                                 </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col'>
                              <label for='suggestion_file'>Label</label>
                              <input type='text' id='suggestion_file' name='suggestion_file' class='form-control suggestion'>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col collapse' id='suggestion_data_x' >
                              <label for='suggestion_data'>Data</label>
                              <input type='text' id='suggestion_data' name='suggestion_data' class='form-control suggestion'>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col'>
                              <label>&nbsp</label>
                              <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="$('#show_suggestionfile').append('&#8226;&nbsp;',$('#suggestion_type').val(),'&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;',$('#suggestion_file').val(),'&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;',$('#suggestion_data').val(),'<br>'); $('#suggestionfile').append($('.blank').val(JSON.stringify($('.suggestion').serializeArray())).clone()); $('#suggestionfile .blank').removeClass('blank'); $('.blank').val(''); $('#suggestion_data, #suggestion_file').val(''); return false;">Add suggestion</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='form-group col'>

                          <div class="col" id="show_suggestionfile">

                          </div>
                          <div class="col" id="suggestionfile">

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>



              <div class='form-group col-auto'>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send Message</button>
              </div>

          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I click send and check the database I am returned with:

```
{"contentInfo":{"fileUrl":"URL","forceRefresh":false},"suggestions":[{"reply":{"text":"","postbackData":"4b214694-afec-4318-bc40-79724a541943"}},{"reply":{"text":"","postbackData":"94211dfa-57d9-426f-b84d-3538627e1fa0"}},{"reply":{"text":"","postbackData":"f8108b93-b1be-4ec5-81bc-6cd1c46ddc70"}}]}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the data to attach to the JSON package, I don't get any errors just nothing there. It's difficult to explain beyond that

Main part of the controller for this:

```
$suggestions = request('suggestion');
        if ($suggestions) {

            foreach ($suggestions as $s) {

                $nd = [];
                $data = json_decode($s,true);
                foreach ($data as $v) {
                    $nd[ str_replace("suggestion_","",$v['name']) ] = $v['value'];
                }

                $suggestion = new Suggestion();
                $suggestion->message_id = $message->id;
                $suggestion->text = $nd['text'];
                $suggestion->content = json_encode([$nd['data']]);
                $suggestion->save();


                switch ($nd['type']) {

                    case 'text':

                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['reply'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id
                        ];
                        break;

                    case 'dialAction':

                        $pn = PhoneNumber::make($nd['data'],['NZ','AU','US']);
                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['action'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id,
                            'dialAction' => [
                                'phoneNumber' => $pn->formatE164()
                            ]
                        ];
                        break;

                    case 'viewLocationAction':

                        list($lat,$lon) = explode(",",$nd['data']);
                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['action'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id,
                            'viewLocationAction' => [
                                'latitude' => $lat,
                                'longitude' => $lon
                            ]
                        ];
                        break;

                    case 'shareLocationAction':

                        list($lat,$lon) = explode(",",$nd['data']);
                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['action'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id,
                            'shareLocationAction' => []
                        ];
                        break;

                    case 'createCalendarEventAction':

                        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$nd['data']);
                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['action'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id,
                            'createCalendarEventAction' => [
                                'startTime' => $date->toISOString(),
                                'endTime' => $date->addHour()->toISOString(),
                                'title' => "RCS Appointment",
                                'description' => file_get_contents('https://loripsum.net/api/1/short/plaintext')
                            ]
                        ];
                        break;

                    case 'openUrlAction':

                        $message_content['suggestions'][]['action'] = [
                            'text' => $nd['text'],
                            'postbackData' => $suggestion->id,
                            'openUrlAction' => [
                                'url' => $nd['data']
                            ]
                        ];
                        break;


                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: not sure the exact setup you have but i would suggest using `dd($request)` in the controller method handling this request to see if the data actual gets back to the controller

Comment: Did you mistakenly use the wrong route? I see you used '/' as your route. 
Could you share your controller code?

Comment: @Ashraf789 I added the main part of the controller, it works for the first tab which is Text but this is the second one being file, I'm not sure where it's going wrong exactly